# Error in transferring data from pandas dataframe to IBM DB2 table

Tags: pandas, db2, ibm-cloud

I am able to establish a connection to db2, hosted on IBM Cloud, but unable to copy the df of size 40000*150 into the table. Here is the code:

```
data = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\PranshuSahijwani\Desktop\kp\data@0409\Pharma_Automated_Snow.xlsx")
data.fillna("Others")

tuple_of_tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in data.values])
#values = ",".join([tuple(x) for x in subset])

cnn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-lon02- 
01.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net;\
PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=uid;PWD=pwd;", "", "")


start = time.time()
placeholders = ', '.join(['?'] * len(data.columns))  
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO zkb70555.regionsAndServers VALUES ( " + placeholders + ")"
stmt_insert = ibm_db.prepare(cnn, insert_sql)
ibm_db.execute_many(stmt_insert, tuple_of_tuples)

end = time.time()
print end-start
```

I am getting the the error as shown:
[image]

What needs to be changed?

Comment: What is the table schema (columns and types)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays passed specifically to `execute_many` must have the same types. The above error indicates that may not be the case in the data inserted. The driver checks the data before sending the requests to the database server and this error is returned by the client.